# How to create a Script that records start and end time data

Tags: google-apps-script

Good evening!
I'm developing a spreadsheet to control some service, but I would like to add a script that record this data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DadM.png)

Thank you very much for attention.

Comment: Hi ! Are you intending to achieve this through [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) or [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)? In your image it is not clear what you want to achieve, **please provide an actual vs desired output** along with a brief description of what you have tried so far. Do you want to record the data when you click the button?

Comment: Hi Mateo! Sorry for not explaining. I want to achieve this through Apps Script. Yes I want to register the information of image when click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a funciton when you click a button with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) you simply need to click on the three top right dots of the button and select `Assign Script` and then write the name of the function of your bounded script (in the example below this would be `myFunction`).

In your case, to get the data you can simply use the methods [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) wich will return the values of the cells in the range you have set. Here a sample code performing this action with self explanatory comments:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // getValues returns a 2D array. For better manipulation I am flattening
  // this into a 1D array
  var data = sheet.getRange('A1:A5').getValues().flat();
  Logger.log(data);
}
```